# Ist „unternehmen“ ein trennbares Verb?

Tags: separable-verb

Beim Übersetzen vom Griechischen ins Deutsche ist mir diese Frage aufgefallen. Welcher der folgenden Sätze ist korrekt?

1. Ich nahm etwas unter.
2. Ich unternahm etwas.

Aus eigener Erfahrung weiß ich, dass der zweite Satz eigentlich der korrekte sein soll, **aber** jetzt bin ich nicht mehr so sicher. Zum Beispiel, *dict.cc* sagt, dass beide korrekt sind:

> VERB[1]  unternehmen [ ' - - - - ] [ugs.: unter den Arm nehmen] | nahm          unter/unternahm [ ' - - - ] | untergenommen

aber wie bei Wikipedia, bin ich immer an der Zuverlässigkeit von *dict.cc* am zweifeln.

Zusammenfassend, welche Form soll ich in meiner Übersetzung verwenden, also welche ist die *korrekte/korrekteste*?

Comment: [Ein Link zu besagter dict.cc-Seite des Verbs](http://www.dict.cc/?s=unternehmen) Mich überrascht wirklich, was ich da lese.

Comment: "Ich nehme unter" habe ich noch nie gehört. Klingt nicht gerade nach Deutsch.  Ich glaube, da mußt du was falsch verstanden haben.

Comment: So, wie das dict.com bringt, kann man das nicht machen. Das scheint was  Regionales zu sein, vielleicht im Berlinerischen. Standard Deutsch ist das auf keinen Fall.

Comment: ich kenn's nicht, insofern ist es nicht Berlinerisch. s... dict.cc ist extrem umfassend, daher kann es schon sein, dass man da rare Sachen findet, allerdings habe ich bei Google nach "untergenommen" gesucht. Es gab ca. 1000 Ergebnisse und die Stichproben, die ich mir angeguckt habe, waren tatsächlich alles falsche geschriebene "unternommen"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Das kommt auf den Kontext an.

Sofern du *unternehmen*, wie *etwas machen*, *aufregendes tun* oder dergleichen benutzt, ist es untrennbar.

> Was machst du heute Abend?
> Ich unternehme etwas mit Hans und Dieter.
>
> Unternimmt ein Unternehmen Unternehmungen?

Sofern du allerdings *etwas unter etwas klemmst*, wie es bei deinem Beispielsatz anklingt, ist es zu trennen. (Allerdings würde ich dann von vornherein den Infinitiv nicht zusammenschreiben.)

> Ich nehme das Paket unter den Arm.

Comment: Viele Dank für die Antwort. Ich habe aber dennoch eine weitere Frage. Warum ist dann *unternehmen* (wie in Ihrer ersten Beispiel) zusammengeschrieben und trennt sich nicht wie z.B. *auffördern* oder irgend ein anderes ähnliches Verb?

Comment: @E.S.L. Unternéhmen versus áuffordern. Das ist zwar nicht unbedingt strikt, weist aber schon darauf hin, dass wir es hier mit einem nichttrennbaren Verb zu tun haben.

Comment: @E.S.L.: Es gibt viele Verben, die sowohl trennbar sein können als auch nicht trennbar, mit unterschiedlicher Bedeutung; oder anders gesagt, unterschiedliche Verben, die im Infinitiv gleich aussehen (aber anders betont werden).

Comment: Mich dünkt, ich ergreife es. Das ist also wie in Griechisch, wo **eimi** *sein* oder *gehen werden* heißen kann, und dies wird von der Betonung entschieden. Vielen Dank nochmal; jetzt sehe ich das Ganze viel klarer.

Comment: Der letzte Teil geht am Ziel vorbei. Die Behauptung des Wörterbuchs war, dass „Ich nehme das Paket unter.“ ein vollständiger Satz ist.

Comment: Es handelt sich hier um zwei verschiedene Wörter: unternehmen und nehmen. 'unternehmen' wird nicht getrennt geschrieben, nehmen kann in einem Satz mit unter verwendet werden, wird dadurch aber nicht zu unternehmen. Also obiger Satz: 'Ich nehme das Paket unter den Arm.' enthält das Verb nehmen, in der Bedeutung wird es auch nicht mit unter zusammengeschrieben.

Comment: @CarstenSchultz irgendwie stimme ich dir zu. Aber so steht das aus Gründen, die sich meiner Erkenntnis entziehen in der zitierten Dict.cc-Version, deswegen war ich der Meinung, das *irgendwie* unterbringen zu müssen.

Comment: @Jan Aber die Frage war doch, ob _unternehmen_ ein trennbares Verb ist. Die Antwort darauf sollte nicht lauten "kommt auf den Kontext an", sondern schlicht "Nein". Dein letzter Satz verwendet nicht das Verb _unternehmen_, sondern _nehmen_.

Comment: @eslukas Welches Wörterbuch benutzt Du? "Mich dünkt, ich ergreife es" hat man, vielleicht, vor zweihundert Jahren gesagt. Heute klingt es nur noch geschraubt und angestaubt, und zwar so sehr, dass es schon wieder komisch ist.

Comment: @Matthias Im Kommentar unter der Frage habe ich des OPs Quelle mal verlinkt. Ich verstehe die Existenz dieses anderen Eintrags (der auch noch eine hochgestellte 1 hat) nicht. Jemand, dessen Umgangssprache das dort verlinkte Verb enthält, möge mich aufklären. Bis dahin glaube ich, dass es ein Fehler ist, der sich am ehesten so erklären lässt.

Comment: @Jan Danke für den Link. Ich hab das auch erst für einen Fehler gehalten, dann aber doch mal noch Duden und Grimm bemüht. Überraschendes Ergebnis: siehe meine Antwort.

Comment: Du behandelst zwei verschiedene Verben, "unternehmen" und "nehmen". Letzteres mit der Präposition "unter". Der Satz "Ich nehme das Paket unter den Arm." hat kein trennbares Verb, so kann da nichts getrennt werden.

Answer (score 5):

Wenn man beispielsweise einen Ausflug macht, spricht man von *etwas unternehmen*. Hier kann und darf man es nicht trennen.

> <s>Wir nahmen einen Ausflug unter.</s>
>   Wir unternahmen einen Ausflug.

Wenn man *etwas unter den Arm nimmt* (Beispiel von Jan: "Ich nehme das Paket unter den Arm"), dann handelt es sich um das Verb *nehmen* plus die Präposition *unter*. Dass es dann getrennt geschrieben werden muss, ist offensichtlich.

Der [Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/unternehmen_greifen_tragen), [Wiktionary](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/unternehmen#Verb.2C_trennbar_.28ugs..29) und eben auch das von dir referenzierte [dict.cc](http://www.dict.cc/?s=unternehmen) kennen aber auch noch eine umgangssprachliche Variante für *unter den Arm nehmen*, das trennbare Verb *unternehmen*. Die Beispiele auf Duden und Wiktionary:

> Das kleine Mädchen nahm sachte den Welpen unter.
>   Er hat das Kind untergenommen.

Wer dieses Verb nicht benutzt, dem erscheint dies fremd und falsch. Dies dürfte auf die Mehrheit der Deutschen zu treffen. Wo man *unternehmen* als trennbares Verb verwendet, kann ich nicht sagen.
Beachte, dass *unternehmen* bereits *unter den Arm nehmen* bedeutet. Folglich sind die beiden folgenden Sätze equivalent, verwenden jedoch zwei verschiedene Verben.

> Ich nehme das Paket unter.
>   Ich nehme das Paket unter den Arm.

Answer (score 4):

Meine instinktive Antwort wäre: **nein**.

Ein Blick in renommiertere Wörterbücher belehrt mich eines besseren:

[Grimms Wörterbuch](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB/?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GU11061#XGU11061) führt die trennbare Variante auf, bezeichnet sie aber als "unüblich".

Auch der [Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/unternehmen_greifen_tragen) listet sie, kennzeichnet sie aber auch als sehr selten.

Also lautet die Antwort: theoretisch kannst Du *unternehmen*, ähnlich wie *unterhaken*, als trennbares Verb benutzen, um auszudrücken, dass etwas "unter den Arm genommen" gehalten oder getragen wird. Praktisch solltest Du Dich nicht wundern, wenn Du dafür erstaunte Blicke erntest. Wenn Du hingegen "handeln, etwas tun" ausdrücken willst, musst Du das Verb untrennbar benutzen, und das ist auch die weitaus üblichere Variante.

Comment: Wo ist denn das Problem? Ein Pärchen an der Rolltreppe am Bahnhof: "Kannst Du den Korb noch unternehmen?" "Ja, gib her, ich nehm ihn noch unter." Wie unterbringen, unterklemmen, ...

Comment: @userunknown D.h. für Dich klingt das normal und richtig? Für mich und offenbar viele andere hier überhaupt nicht. Aber einen Grund wird es ja haben, dass der Duden die trennbare Variante noch führt. Könnte es sein, dass da ein regionaler Bezug dabei ist?

Comment: Für mich klingt vieles richtig, was selten ist. Es scheinen ja viele als Theorie mit sich rumzutragen, dass ein Ausdruck nicht nur möglich und legitim sein muss, sondern auch der häufigste. Was soll das? Wen interessiert wie häufig ein Ausdruck ist? Ein rarer Ausdruck ist nicht weniger richtig, nur weil er seltener ist. Im Alltag spielt diese Theorie keine Rolle - niemand würde einen anderen korrigieren und sagen: "Das heißt 'selten', nicht 'rar'". Aber wenn 's ans Theoretisieren geht spinnen sich alle was zurecht, erkennen Unterschiede wo keine sind usw.